# What is wrong in this random string printing code?

Tags: c++, string, random

Im trying to print X (x = user input) number to lines of string array (Alpha) and if there is "A" in the line it should print something (string or random number) in that line, for example "This line has "A" " . I cant figure out whats wrong in my code, like this line in code is not working right:
    (Alpha[dist(gen)] == Alpha[0])

It is printing out the ("This line has "A" ) in the line which has other string Alphabets (S,P C etc)

```
#include <climits>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num;
    const int SIZE = 6;

    cout << "How many iterations: ";
    cin >> num;
    string Aplha[SIZE] = {"A", "D", "P", "E", "C", "S"};

    random_device randNum;
    mt19937 gen(randNum());
    uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, 5);
    uniform_int_distribution<> distRange(INT_MIN, INT_MAX);

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        cout << Alpha[dist(gen)];
        if(Alpha[dist(gen)] == Alpha[0]) {
            cout << " this line has A " << distRange(gen);
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Result should be...

### if a line has "A" then :

```
A this line has A 123231315
D
P
D
S
A this line has A 845421541
C
```

---

the result im getting is like this...

```
How many iterations: 10
S
S this line has A 1950029843
S
C this line has A -145672138
A
C
D
C
E
S
```

Comment: Please make it easier to help by presenting the expected output and the output you're getting. It's not clear what's what (in my book).

Comment: dist(gen) is being used two times within your loop, this is a function that does what?

Comment: @TedLyngmo hi ted, i just edited my original post please see the last item thats what the result im getting..

Comment: @Areeb Great! It's much better

Answer (score 0):

`Alpha[dist(gen)]` that you print is not the same `Alpha[dist(gen)]` that you check against `Alpha[0]`. Each call to `dist(gen)` produces a different random number.

Comment: Yes, that is what appears to me as well, wasnt 100% sure what dist() was doing though

Comment: @DanielAaron It is doing what [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) says it would.

Comment: Since `Alpha[dist(gen)]` is in the same { } so i believe it should be having the same value until the next rotation of the loop so  when i'm calling the == operator to check the value it should be same as the one which was just printed....please correct me if im wrong

Comment: You are wrong. Consider yourself corrected. Add a line like this: `cout << dist(gen) << dist(gen);` - might prove illuminating.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  yeah i just checked u are right, can you show me the solution please?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the next two lines. Each time you call `dist(gen)` you get different indexes.

```
cout << Alpha[dist(gen)];   
if (Alpha[dist(gen)] == Alpha[0])
```

I assume, it should be like bellow.

```
const size_t j = dist(gen);
cout << Alpha[j];   
if (Alpha[j] == Alpha[0])
```

Comment: I tried that but its not random number anymore, you code is making dist(gen) constant number which is giving me a single string Alphabet in output.

Comment: `const size_t j = dist(gen);` must be inside the loop, exactly like in the answer.